# How to use scp command in paramiko

Tags: python, scp, paramiko

I am using two commands in paramiko python module "find" and "scp".
Find command is working fine and giving the correct output but scp is not giving any output.
I tried with following code:

```
import paramiko

class SSH:

    def ssh_Connection(self):
        try:
            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.ssh.connect('host_name',username='user',password='pass')

        except Exception, e:
            print "================================================"
            print 'ERROR: Remote connection failed with %s' % e
            print "================================================"


    def ssh_Commands(self):
        try:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('find /result/main/ -name "*new.txt*"')
            for line in stdout:
                a = line.strip('\n')
                print a
                if a:
                    cmd = 'scp -r %s redhat@192.168.56.32:/results/main/' % a
                    print cmd
                    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
                    print stdout.read()
                    print stderr.read()

            self.ssh.close()
        except Exception, e:
            print "================================================"
            print 'ERROR: Commands Execution failed with %s' % e
            print "================================================"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = SSH()
    a.ssh_Connection()
    a.ssh_Commands()
```

But this program is not working for me..

```
Throwing an error:
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

How can use scp in paramiko...any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SFTPClient` of paramiko to copy files from local to remote server.

There is put method for of [SFTPClient](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html) which will copy local file to the remote server.

Comment: +1 This solution seems more portable, it will work even if paramiko client is run on Windows. I would even search for files using it, but `find` works locally and is faster.

Comment: I tried SFTPClient it is working... but how can we find the file and then download it? I do not want to create another connection for SFTPClient

Comment: You can call `find -type f -name new.txt` command on remote server and get the output. From that output download those files.

Answer (score 1):

The server (`host_name`) on which you are performing the commands doesn't have proper SSH access to the server you are trying to scp to (192.168.56.32), that's why it generates the error `Host key verification failed` (which means that the host key for 192.168.56.32 in the `known_hosts` file on `host_name` doesn't match the key that 192.168.56.32 is returning).

Either fix the host key, or try running scp like this:

```
scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r %s ...
```

(also be aware that if the filenames contain spaces, your scp command will fail, use `"%s"` on your scp command line instead).

Comment: I have replaced 'scp -r %s redhat@192.168.56.32:/results/main/' % a with 'scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r %s redhat@192.168.56.32:/results/main/' % a   It is not displaying any thing, not even my find command output.

Comment: Try sshing into `host_name` and perform the command manually to see if it works.

Comment: showing one Warning: Permanently added '192.168.56.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

Comment: That's okay, although it would suggest that the scp-command was never called from your script. Not sure why and rather hard to debug from here. Make sure you are using the exact same variables as your script: same user, password, etc.

Comment: Every thing is same but do not know why it is not working... I tried using SFTPClient, i am able to download the file but the how to find a file is a problem

Comment: `scp` requiring a password based authentication, and that shell is not visible. Hence nothing is appearing.

Try `sshpass -p <<PWD>> scp -r .....`